# How to open other folder without closing the first in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (Open Folder) the current opened folder was closed before opening the new.

What I can do to have both opened?

**EDITED: Workaround**

Visual Studio Code has the concept of *Workspace*. If I open a folder in an empty session, then I can open another using the menú option *File, Add Folder tho Worspace...*.

Then I have two folders opened in an *unseved workspace*. If I want I can *Save Workspace As...* a file and latter *Open Worskpace from file...*

Comment: According to [Atom.io Blog](http://blog.atom.io/2015/04/15/multi-folder-projects.html) you could try Ctrl+Alt+O.

Comment: I just experienced this exact situation earlier this morning.

Comment: @Seth this is not Atom.io. Visual Studio Code is a lighweight code editor that is part of Visual Studio. Also, I tried CTRL-K, CTRL-ALT-O and just CTRL-ALT-O and the status bar informs me these are not valid commands.

Comment: Which is originally based on Atom if I'm not mistaken. Hence it would be worth a try whenever it works. But you're right that it seems to be based on Electron now (a continuation of the atom framework?). So it might not work.

Comment: It doesn't. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been reported as an open request in Github since November 2015: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/396

It is still listed as open, indicating they do not consider in impossible, but it is not yet developer or implemented.

Further, this question has been asked on our sister site Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234146/open-multiple-folders-in-visual-studio-code/43308278

So, short answer: **It's not currently supported.**

**Workaround:**

Depending how you use your multiple folders, you could use SymLinks to get basically the same functionality.

In your main VS Code folder, open an elevated Command Prompt and enter:

```
mklink /D C:\VSCode\Folder\Symlink D:\Other\Folder
```

Or if you're using PowerShell:

```
CMD /C mklink /D C:\VSCode\Folder\Symlink D:\Other\Folder
```

As far as VS Code can tell you're still only using a single folder, but you'll be able to access the symlinked folders easily in the Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

File > New Window > *Open the folder that you want*